# Create AirPort network from the command line?

Tags: macos, wifi, airport

Is it possible to put my AirPort in access point mode, so it creates an infrastructure (ie, non-ad-hoc) network from the command line on OS X?

Similar to using System Preferences -> Sharing -> Internet -> Share from … to computers using WiFi.

Comment: This won't answer your question but might be of interest: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport

Comment: Unfortunately `airport` doesn't seem to do anything related. In fact, `airport -s` doesn't show anything when running in hostap mode.

Answer (score 3):

After some hours of digging through the internet, it seems that the only way to put an airport in HostAP ("software base station") mode in OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion is to programatically call a the internal, undocumented, `startHostAPModeWithSSID` method.

I've updated the one example I could find online, and it does seem to work, with the one caveat that only WEP, not WPA, can be used: https://gist.github.com/4418079